# Return most recent rows and rows that match other criteria without duplicate in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have data that looks like this

`Table "People"`

```
+----------+-------------+----------------------------------+
|id        |age          |name        |job        |gender   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|1         |26           |joe         |Welder     |m        |
|2         |50           |Mary        |Juggler    |f        |
|3         |26           |Henry       |Dancer     |m        |
|4         |31           |Pat         |Trucker    |f        |
|5         |26           |Frank       |Designer   |m        |
+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to return the last 2 entries, so I tried `SELECT * ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 2` but this also returns people with age over 30 without returning duplicate rows.

My intended result will be to get Frank, Pat and Mary.

Comment: UNION is your friend

Comment: @RickSmith `SELECT * FROM People WHERE age>'30' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5` but that only return people who are over 30, not the last few people AND people over 30

Comment: @Strawberry I always thought UNION was for more than one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you still need an answer:

```
(SELECT id, age, name
 FROM People 
 ORDER BY ID DESC
 LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT id, age, name
 FROM People
 WHERE Age>30)
```